# React error- Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im using typescript, not too familiar with and am getting the following err for when I want to copy a group.

This is my subGroups data (It's an array):

```
const subGroupsData = currentGroup().subGroups;
```

When i want to copy that array like this;

```
const newSubGroups: GroupRepresentation[] = [...subGroupsData];
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'GroupRepresentation[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Any help would be so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Currently typescript *thinks* `subGroupsData` might be `undefined`, visible from the error message:

```
Type 'GroupRepresentation[] | undefined' must have a...
                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

so you have to *convince* it otherwise:

For example:

```
const newSubGroups: GroupRepresentation[] = undefined === subGroupsData
                                          ? []
                                          : [...subGroupsData];
```